# Why does multitouch scrolling in Word 2019 scroll in both directions?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, touchpad, scrolling

I'm running Word 2019 on a Dell XPS 13.

When I use two fingers on the touchpad to scroll down through documents in Word, the document will start scrolling up, and then -- while I'm still scrolling down -- change directions and start going down. Vice versa when I'm scrolling up.

I don't see this happening in Chrome, Explorer, Acrobat, etc., or even within other Microsoft Office applications.

Word is on Version 1906; I'm not sure what other versions I've had, but I believe the problem has existed since inital installation. Windows 10 is up to date, and all drivers appear to be up to date, as well. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Do you recall this happening on previous versions of Word?

Comment: I haven't seen this in previous versions, but 2019 is the only version I've had installed on this machine.

Comment: You have Office 2019 installed.  When I am asking about previous versions, I am talking about previous updates (1905,1904, ect).  I am asking you if this is new behavior or this behavior has always existed.  Instead of submitting a comment, go ahead and edit your question, to provide the required clarification.

Comment: Ah, I see. Done.